# KnockoutJs issue rendering children of parent loop

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js

I have what is clearly a "hello world" issue with parsing an array of objects (itself a child). I am using the ko.mappings functionality as this apparently is the way to parse a JSON structure into an observable array. But my inner child loop inside is not iterating the children correctly. If I dump the collection, it has the right objects, but will only create a single list item. i.e.

```
//viewmodel.js
//get my json as a view model
that.vpc_instances = mapping.fromJSON(response.data);

//view.html
<ul data-bind="foreach: vpc_instances"  class="list-group">
 .....
 Tags
 <ul data-bind"foreach: _tags">
     //I get one element with the list of objects
     // was hoping I could do "data-bind='text: _tags[$index].Name'" etc, but only 1 li is generated
     <li data-bind="text: _tags" />
</ul>
```

produces

```
Tags
 [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

I can't see why the loop only executes a single time, given it knows it has five children. My data looks like this...

![image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ul data-bind"foreach: _tags">
```

This needs an = after data-bind

Once you are inside the foreach for _tags you don't need to reference _tags anymore as the context is then each tag. Use something like:

```
<li data-bind="text: Name" />
```

Comment: Ha! Thanks. Spot on. Pesky changing context! Many thanks